# xkbcomp at startup in kde

Tags: kubuntu, kde, autostart, xkb

I'm using kubuntu 20.04 and want to run `xkbcomp ~/.Xkeymap $DISPLAY` at startup to load a custom keymap. To this end I created a script with the content

```
#!/bin/bash

touch ~/test
xkbcomp ~/.Xkeymap $DISPLAY
```

and put it in `~/.config/autostart-scripts`. I made it executable, and I see that it's indeed running at startup because the `touch` command timestamps a file in the home directory. However, the keys are not correctly remapped, and I have to rerun the script manually each time (which has the desired effect).

I assume the problem is that the scripts in the autostart directory are run too early during startup, *before* kde loads its own keymaps?

Is that the correct diagnosis? And does anybody know a way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't tell if your assumption is correct, but possibly you can find out by delaying the execution of the `xkbcomp` command, i.e. replacing

```bash
xkbcomp ~/.Xkeymap $DISPLAY
```

with

```bash
{
    sleep 3
    xkbcomp ~/.Xkeymap $DISPLAY
} &
```

Comment: good idea, i'll try that

Comment: It works! Even with `sleep 1`. Thanks!

Comment: @user313032: Great, sometimes you get lucky. :)